# Create Multiple Select Using Bootstrap Form.Control

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a select using React.Form from React-Bootstrap. I expected something like this(this ss is from react-bootstrap-multiselect):
[image: expected]


But I got this kind of result:

[image: wrong]


This is my code:

> ```
> <Form.Control
>   required
>   as="select"
>   type="select"
>   id="instructors"
>   value={instructors}
>   onChange={handleChange}
>   multiple
> >
>   <option hidden value key="blankChoice">
>     Pilih Instruktur...
>   </option>
>   {items
>     ? items.map((item, index) => {
>         return <option value={item.id}>test{index}</option>;
>       })
>     : null}
> </Form.Control>
> ```

Actually I can just use React-Select library, but I try not using too many libraries, and since I already use React-Bootstrap, it will be take another effort to match the style with another library that I will use. 


Thanks!